# preg_match has string size limit

Tags: php, preg-match

preg_match has limit of str on PHP 5.2.5

```
<?php
    $str1 = 'a@b%c@d' . str_repeat ('=', 33326);
    $str2 = 'a@b%c@d' . str_repeat ('=', 33327);
    $regexp = '/^(.*)@(.*)%(.*)$/si';

    echo preg_match ($regexp, $str1) ? "Correct " : "Wrong ";  // works correctly
    echo "\n";
    echo preg_match ($regexp, $str2) ? "Correct " : "Wrong ";  // exhibits the bug
    echo "\n";
```

Comment: Its not a bug, its a feature: http://php.net/pcre.configuration#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[preg_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php) after the second call returns 2 (=PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR) so you might want to raise this value.

Comment: Backtrack limit was exhausted!