# PHP looping failure when array reaches certain size

Tags: php, arrays, memory, loops

This has been edited a bit, sorry if any comments are out of context.

So, I'm working on the targeting challenge from gild.com. My solution concept is:

1) determine the worth of each target option (as defined by: how many options remain if it is struck)

2) slice the array at that strike point

3) drop any items with a Value lower that the last strike

4) repeat until array is empty

5) return count of strikes

Here's my latest code. I am on shared 1&1 hosting so I don't have direct access to error logs. I had a workaround in place but it's no longer writing to that file (so I'm guessing the error has changed). But when I was getting output, it was always an `undefined offset`...

**UPDATE:** now I've been playing around with echoing output from various points to see what's happening, and I found that this prevents a formal error, but it stops echoing after the `depth++;` loop

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$targets=array();
$file="http://www.gild.com/coding_test_cases/missile/missile-a.in";
$input=file_get_contents($file);
$input=str_replace("\n\n","\n",$input);
$targets=explode("\n",$input);
if(strlen($targets[count($targets)-1])==0){
    array_pop($targets);
}

$rich=array();
$order=array();
while(count($targets)>0){
    for($i=0;$i<count($targets);$i++){
        $key=$i;
        $depth=0;
        while($key<count($targets)){
            if($targets[$key]>$targets[$i]){
                $depth++;
            }
            $key++;
        }
        $rich[$i]=$depth;
        echo "."; //-----------------------------------I will make it to the screen
    }
    echo "hi"; //--------------------------------------------------------I will not

    $last_strike=$targets[array_pop(array_keys($rich,max($rich)))];
    array_push($order,$last_strike);
    $targets=array_slice($targets,array_pop(array_keys($rich,max($rich)))+1);
    $rich=array();
    $c=count($targets);
    for($b=0;$b<$c;$b++){
        if($targets[$b]<$last_strike){
            array_splice($targets,$b,1,true);
            $b--;
            $c--;
        }
    }
}
echo count($order)."\n";
?>
```

Comment: Check your web server error log to see what the 500 error is all about

Comment: @Robot Woods: What exactly are you trying to do with the code. I think it can be improved, but I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Because it's shared hosting, I can't access the logs. I did this: http://faq.1and1.com/miscellaneous/14.html and the error I get it: `(Notice) Undefined offset:  1` which sounds like a function error, but if that were the case wouldn't it always fail?

Comment: @PeeHaa: It's the first step in my approach to this http://www.gild.com/challenges/details/225

Comment: @Robot Woods: Don't want to spoil it for you. Is it ok if I post what I would do?

Comment: Definitely, if I didn't want to learn something, I wouldn't be here :)

Comment: I've read the challenge you reference above. Are you trying to construct all the possible target sequences, then compare which one is the best? That would make you run out of memory quickly. If so, you might be better off having a `$best_sequence = array()` array, then constructing sequences systematically and testing against it.  That way you only have three arrays in memory at once -- the input array, the best array, and the array you are creating to see if it's better than the best. Good luck!

Comment: No, I'm assigning each target a richness value (how many target options would remain if you struck that one), then I'll take the highest, slice the array at that point, take the next highest, etc. However, your comment does make me realize that I could overwrite the values in targets WITH the richness value...I'll see if that changes anything. thanks

Comment: no change, thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but isn't your entire code snippet equivalent to this?

```
$rich = range($_GET['lim'] - 1, 0);
echo $rich[0];
```

As for your actual error, it sounds like a memory allocation problem. Try rethinking your algorithm for this problem.

Comment: well that was just an illustrative example of the buggy behavior. I've now posted the real code. I think the current hiccup is that I'm trying to loop through an array, dropping particular values as I go...and since the array is changing, the loops over-reaches...

Comment: I fixed that particular piece, but the overall script still fails. It works fine with a small array, but at some mystery size, things fall apart. now that you see the actual loop, do you have advice memory-wise? Thanks

Comment: I will have to rethink my approach, if there are 30k targets, that depth++ loop will run nearly half a billion times just on the first pass

Comment: Have you tried to use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 300 seconds = 5 minutes` and `ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "100000000"); // default 100k = "100000"`? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173223/preg-match-has-string-size-limit

Answer (score 0):

I think reason that you have 500 error instead of Human-readable error is switched off [`dislay_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) ini setting.
Try to switch on it or find error message  in your Apache error log