# PHP - Fill the arrays in a sequential manner until reaching a maximum length

Tags: php, arrays, regex, loops, sequential

I need to extract data from a text file formatted in a such way, using PHP:

```
BEGIN
#1 
#2 
#3 
#4 
#5 
#6 
1       2015-05-31  2001-11-24  'Name Surname'      ID_1        0 
2       2011-04-01  ?           ?                   ID_2        1 
2       2013-02-24  ?           ?                   ID_3        1 
2       2014-02-28  ?           'Name Surname'      ID_4        2 
END
```

The informations are organized with the logic of an array like the following:

```
Array ( [#1] => 1 [#2] => 2015-05-31 [#3] => 2001-11-24 [#4] => 'Name Surname' [#5] => ID_1 [#6] => 0 )
Array ( [#1] => 2 [#2] => 2011-04-01 [#3] => ?           [#4] => ?             [#5] => ID_2 [#6] => 1 )
Array ( [#1] => 2 [#2] => 2013-02-24 [#3] => ?           [#4] => ?             [#5] => ID_3 [#6] => 1 )
Array ( [#1] => 2 [#2] => 2014-02-28 [#3] => ?           [#4] => 'Name Surname' [#5] => ID_4 [#6] => 2 )
```

I was searching a way to obtain that output. I'm using this code:

```
<?php 
    //ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

    function startsWith($str, $char){
        return $str[0] === $char;
    }

    $txt_path = "./test.txt";
    $txt_data = @file_get_contents($txt_path) or die("Could not access file: $txt_path");
    //echo $txt_data;

    $loop_pattern = "/BEGIN(.*?)END/s";
    preg_match_all($loop_pattern, $txt_data, $matches);
    $loops = $matches[0];
    //print_r($loops);
    $loops_count = count($loops);
    //echo $loops_count; // number of loops into the file
    foreach ($loops as $key => $value) {
        $value = trim($value);
        $pattern = array("/[[:blank:]]+/", "/BEGIN(.*)/", "/END(.*)/");
        $replacement = array(" ", "", "");
        $value = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $value);
        //print_r($value);
        //echo "<br><br>";
        $value_array = explode("\n", $value);
        $value_array_clean = array_filter($value_array, 'strlen');
        $value_array_clean_reindex = array_values($value_array_clean);
        //print_r($value_array_clean_reindex);
        //echo "<br><br>";
        $keys = array();
        $values = array();
        foreach ($value_array_clean_reindex as $key => $value) {
            $value = trim($value);
            if ( startsWith($value, "#") ) {
                array_push($keys, $value);
                $keys_count = count($keys);
            } else {
                array_push($values, $value);
                $values_count = count($values);

                $loop_dic = array();
                foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                    $value = trim($value);
                    preg_match_all("/'(?:.|[^'])*'|\S+/", $value, $matches);
                    //print_r($matches[0]);
                    $loop_dic = array_combine($keys, $matches[0]);
                }

                print_r($loop_dic);
                echo "<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

And it gives me the wanted output:

```
Array ( [#1] => 1 [#2] => 2015-05-31 [#3] => 2001-11-24 [#4] => 'Name Surname' [#5] => ID_1 [#6] => 0 )
Array ( [#1] => 2 [#2] => 2011-04-01 [#3] => ? [#4] => ? [#5] => ID_2 [#6] => 1 )
Array ( [#1] => 2 [#2] => 2013-02-24 [#3] => ? [#4] => ? [#5] => ID_3 [#6] => 1 )
Array ( [#1] => 2 [#2] => 2014-02-28 [#3] => ? [#4] => 'Name Surname' [#5] => ID_4 [#6] => 2 )
```

But sometime occurs a problem at level of the command:

```
$loop_dic = array_combine($keys, $matches[0]);
```

I understood that, in the original text file, with very long lines, these are broken, generating a new line; instead of:

```
2       2014-02-28  ?           'Name Surname'      ID_4        2
```

the line is broken like this:

```
2       2014-02-28  ?           'Name Surname'      
ID_4        2
```

So, when I explode the string by `\n`, it occurs an error in the length of the two arrays that then I combine.

I would ask you an alternative to solve this issue, obtaining arrays of equal length, also if a break occurs in the original file.

Seaching on the web, I found [array_fill](http://php.net/array_fill); maybe, if I know (by `count`) the number of keys in its array for each loop ([#1],...,[#6]), could be possible to loop and fill arrays for values, adding them sequentially until the max lenght of each array for the values.

Thank you for your attention and help.

**EDIT #1**

Thanks to @fusion3k for his solution!
Checking the behaviour with some input files it shows two other problems:

**1)**  Analyzing some errors, I discovered that sometime the input file uses *double quotes* (instead of *single quotes*), and there are blocks of text in multiple lines between *semicolon* too, like the following:

```
;This is some text
in multiline with "double 
quotes" too
;
```

that need to be considered as a single value for a given key, for which the value needs to be inline, like the @fusion3k code do, replacing `\n` with  (a space). I'm trying to merge the @fusion3k's working code with the one elaborated to solve this behaviour. The file structure could be like this one:

```
BEGIN
#1 
#2 
#3 
#4 
#5 
#6 
1       2015-05-31  2001-11-24  "Name Surname"      ID_1        0 
2       2011-04-01  ?           ?                   ID_2        1 
2       2013-02-24  ?           ?                   ID_3        1 
2       2014-02-28  ?           "Name Surname"      ID_4        2 
;This is some text
in multiline with "double 
quotes" too
;
2016-01-22  ?           "Name Surname"      ID_5        2 
END
```

which should generate something like the above working code, but considering the presence of different text block delimitators, like *semicolon* (`;`), *single quotes* (`'`) or, like in some other files, *double quotes* (`"`), to delimit a block of text that must be considered as single value for a key, like in this array relative to the above text file content:

```
Array ( [#1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 [4] => This is some text in multiline with "double quotes" too ) [#2] => Array ( [0] => 2015-05-31 [1] => 2011-04-01 [2] => 2013-02-24 [3] => 2014-02-28 [4] => 2016-01-22 ) [#3] => Array ( [0] => 2001-11-24 [1] => ? [2] => ? [3] => ? [4] => ? ) [#4] => Array ( [0] => Name Surname [1] => ? [2] => ? [3] => Name Surname [4] => Name Surname ) [#5] => Array ( [0] => ID_1 [1] => ID_2 [2] => ID_3 [3] => ID_4 [4] => ID_5 ) [#6] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 2 ) )
```

I worked on a simple string, to find a "working" regular expression that considers (*semicolon*) AND (*single quotes* OR *double quotes*). For now I haven't found files which uses all the three delimitators to delimit block of text, but it seems to be possible to find *semicolon*+*single_quotes* OR *semicolon*+*double_quotes* OR only *single_quotes* OR only *double_quotes*; would be good find a solution with all the three types of delimitators in the same text file...:

```
$string = 'something here 
;and there
;
oh, "that\'s all!"';
$string = str_replace( "\n", " ", $string );
$origin = array("/[[:blank:]]+/", "/\"/", "/;/");
$replacement = array(" ", "\" ", "; ");
$string = preg_replace($origin, $replacement, $string);
$pattern = '/([;"])\s+/';
print_r(array_filter(preg_split( $pattern, $string ), 'strlen'));
```

This the output (as wanted):

```
Array ( [0] => something here [1] => and there [2] => oh, [3] => that's all! )
```

Note the text block between *semicolons*: it starts always in a new line, with a *semicolon* at the beginning, and it finishes with a *semicolon* in a new line, after which starts another newline.

I don't know if it could be written in a better and fastest way... I tried then to merge it with the @fusion3k's code, working on the above text file content, but without success. I tried an `if/elseif/else` construct like this one:

```
if ( preg_match('/;(.*?);|\'(.*?)\'/', $value, $matches) ) {// semicolon with single quotes in the $value string
    $value = str_replace( "\n", " ", $value );
    $origin = array("/[[:blank:]]+/", "/'/", "/;/");
    $replacement = array(" ", "' ", "; ");
    $value = preg_replace($origin, $replacement, $value);
    $pattern = '/'.str_repeat( "([;'])\s+", count( $keys ) ).'/';
    print_r(array_filter(preg_split( $pattern, $value ), 'strlen')); // I would have an array of values of the same length of the array for the keys
    echo "<br><br>";
} elseif ( preg_match('/;(.*?);|"(.*?)"/', $value, $matches) ) {// semicolon with double quotes in the $value string
    $value = str_replace( "\n", " ", $value );
    $origin = array("/[[:blank:]]+/", "/\"/", "/;/");
    $replacement = array(" ", "\" ", "; ");
    $value = preg_replace($origin, $replacement, $value);
    $pattern = '/'.str_repeat( "([;\"])\s+", count( $keys ) ).'/';
    print_r(array_filter(preg_split( $pattern, $value ), 'strlen')); // I would have an array of values of the same length of the array for the keys
    echo "<br><br>";
} else {// neither single quotes (or double quotes) nor semicolon in the $value string
    $pattern = '/'.str_repeat( "(\S+)\s+", count( $keys ) ).'/';
    preg_match_all( $pattern, $value, $matches );
    //print_r($matches);
    //echo "<br><br>";
    $loop_dic = array_combine( $keys, array_slice( $matches, 1 ) );
    print_r( $loop_dic ); // this is good...maybe in a better way?
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

The only working code is the last else, which uses the @fusion3k's code.

**2)**  The second behaviour (probably already solved), happens when the file is very big. The command:

```
$loop_pattern = "/BEGIN(.*?)END/s";
preg_match_all($loop_pattern, $txt_data, $matches);
$loops = $matches[0];
//print_r($loops);
$loops_count = count($loops);
//echo $loops_count; // number of loops into the file
```

does not take all the loops in the files (big file).
Probably the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173223/preg-match-has-string-size-limit), I think. So, setting:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "100000000"); // default 100k = "100000"
```

seems to solve it, but I don't know if it's the only way: indeed, if the file is big (17MB or up), there is a little not responding time of the browser (I'm testing on Firefox up to date), before the page has finished loading... Would be good to parse the whole file in blocks until its full size, maybe, but how to do it?

Thank you very much for your attention and help

Comment: If the broken lines are ever broken by `ID_`, you can pre-process the string: `$txt_data = str_replace( "\nID_", "ID_", $txt_data );`

Comment: Thanks @fusion3k. No, there isn't a rule for the level of the break in the line. I only understood that the problem is for that reason, so that the `explode` command by `\n` fails, generating arrays of different length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your problem, common approach is to count retrieved matches and — if they are less than keys — continue the loop without re-init `$loop_dic`.

I propose you an *inverted* approach: instead of exploding the string by line, replace newlines with spaces before retrieving values: your string structure is solid enough to allow this approach, and you know the field number, so this approach should work.

The code outside main `foreach` loop doesn't change. In the same way, the code to retrieve text wrapped by `BEGIN ... END` is untouched:

```
foreach( $loops as $key => $value ) 
{
    $value = trim( $value );
    $pattern = array( "/[[:blank:]]+/", "/BEGIN(.*)/", "/END(.*)/" );
    $replacement = array( " ", "", "" );
    $value = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $value );
```

To retrieve the keys, we use a `preg_match_all()`, then we delete relative lines with `preg_replace()`:

```
    preg_match_all( '/^#\d+/m', $value, $matches );
    $keys = $matches[0];

    $value = preg_replace( '/^#\d+\s*/m', '', $value );
```

Now, in `$value` we have only data lines. We replace all newlines with spaces:

```
    $value = str_replace( "\n", " ", $value );
```

Then, we construct a row pattern by repeating field pattern for keys number and we retrieve all rows by `preg_match_all()`:

```
    $pattern = '/'.str_repeat( "('[^']+'|\S+)\s+", count( $keys ) ).'/';
    preg_match_all( $pattern, $value, $matches );
```

At the end, we use `array_slice()` to delete global matches, we combine it with `$keys` and we have desired result. The `foreach` loop can be closed:

```
    $values = array_combine( $keys, array_slice( $matches, 1 ) );
}
```

<kbd>**[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/40yKyF)**</kbd>

The main difference between mine `$values` and your `$loop_dic` is that in `$values` main array you have the columns, but if you prefer an array by rows you can easily transform it.

I have tested the code with many different “broken lines”, and it works. I suggest you to carefully test it with different strings to see if it works fine in any circumstance.

Comment: It's so wonderful!!! I understood your approach: I will try it tomorrow with some input file to check everything! Thank you so much for your time!! Regards

Comment: I could not wait: I tested it on different files and it all looks incredibly perfect and very fast!!! For a file of 170925 lines and 17569148 characters it takes 0.2635 seconds before the whole page finish loading :) It's so great! Thank you, @fusion3k, I will accept your answer!! Regards!!

Comment: I added an edit #1 to explain two behaviours shown by some text file content. Maybe you could take a look. Thank you so much!!